# How to force a cart update on WooCommerce (without changing quantity)

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, woothemes

I have been trying to disable VAT on products purchased by someone in the EU, if they have a valid VAT number.

I purchased a [plugin from WooThemes](http://www.woothemes.com/products/eu-vat-number/), which is supposed to do what I am after above, but because I am not using the standard WooCommerce/PayPal checkout experience, and instead I am using a [PayPal Express plugin](http://www.woothemes.com/products/paypal-express/) that they offer, so the hooks/actions that the EU VAT Number plugin used are no longer being called I assume.

I was trying to reassign this plugins functions to different hooks, so that it would work as requested. I forced the plugin to appear on the cart.php WooCommerce template, rather than the default Shipping Details page, and then added the `process_checkout` function [which just processes the VAT number entered and removes VAT if its valid] to the `woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update` hook from WooCommerce. From what I can tell, this action is run whenever 'Update Cart' is clicked *BUT* it doesn't seem to run unless the quantity has changed **AND** also doesn't seem to run unless the quantity is a *new* quantity that hasn't already been calculated and cached.

I really just need to force `woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update` to run as soon  as the button is pressed, (i think,).

If I am heading down the wrong path that would also be great to hear

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got the right idea, but you just need to do it on a different hook.

Instead of woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity, I'd try woocommerce_after_cart_totals and see if that works better for you.